# Differentiate between Buy and Exit alerts in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I have written an algorithm for auto live trading , where i have linked TRadingview with Tradetron to automate my trading .

From tradingview , i am trying to create two alerts " one for buy and one for exit"

Now , the pine script which i have written includes this piece of code :

```
if(EnterBuy and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long,when=EnterBuy)
if(EnterSell and strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit the buy","Buy", limit = close)
```

I want to link my alerts to buy and exit accordingly. But what i am observing is , if any of the above condition is satisfied , tradingview is firing two alerts .whereas i want the alerts to be conditional

Answer (score 0):

Use the `alert_message` argument of the `strategy.entry` and `strategy.exit` functions.

```
if(EnterBuy and strategy.position_size <= 0)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long,when=EnterBuy, alert_message="Enter Long")
if(EnterSell and strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit the buy","Buy", limit = close, alert_message="Exit Long")
```